# Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API - How to integrate iOS Framework without cocoa pods?

Tags: ios, sdk, cocoapods, azure-cognitive-services, face

I am looking at integrating the Face iOS SDK found here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-face-ios

Unfortunately the only option Microsoft gives is using cocoa pods and using cocoa pods is not an option for this project so here are my questions:

How can I extract the SDK out of a cocoa pod into a stand alone project? I Is this even possible?

Is there a way to just download the Face iOS SDK and integrate it without cocoa pods that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocapods is just a library manager for easy integration, if you do not want to have that tool as dependency you can build the library from source code by yourself.

If you have any further problem about build or integration, feel free to update the problem.

Bests,
Xuan (Sean) Hu.

Comment: Hi Xuan, Thank you for your response. Yes this is exactly my question. Where can I find the clean library/source code so that I can integrate it myself, without having to cleanup and revert all the cocoapod setup?

Comment: You can just open the project in Xcode and build it. There should have no internal cocapods dependency. AFAIK, cocapods is just a configuration file so that we can post the library via pods commands line. Feel free to ping me if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Hi Xuan. Are you talking about the demo project provided? I only need the library to integrate into a new project. Stripping it out from the demo project is a really poor solution for a company like Microsoft. Any other vendor will make their libraries available decluttered of demo files and unnecessary configuration so that developers can easily integrate them without bloating any project with unnecessary code. Let me know if I'm missing something and in fact I can just download the library and add it to one of my projects easily.

Comment: The demo project and actual library are two separate projects. Actually, the library are just some classes implemented in obj-c and it located here https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-iOS/tree/master/Pod/Classes.

Comment: Great, thank you Xuan, that is exactly the information I was looking for. So technically just dragging and dropping those into my project should do the trick or is there additional setup required? BTW great job with the Faces engine. It does a really good job.

Comment: Yep for confirmation, And I believe cocopods will do the same kind of things. Enjoy your journey with Cognitive Services - Face API.